# Sync Docker images from two Repository

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, gitlab, amazon-ecr

I have a Docker image from a vendor stored in Amazon Elastic Container Registry (ECR). My goal is to pull this image, examine its source code, and then push it to our own ECR. However, I'm uncertain about how to review the source code without downloading the Docker image to my local machine. I'm also looking for a solution that can be integrated with our Pull Request process and code approval system on GitLab. Does anyone have any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Can you elaboarate on what you mean by `"examine its source code"`? Are you looking for vulnerability scan on the image?

Comment: I am looking what has changed in the source code. I need to review that code and make sure that meets our security requirements.